# Repartiera meaning (or what is subjunctive preterite imperfect?)

Tags: gramática, definiciones

I'm to the point in my Spanish study that I'm reading books.  I often come across words that I might know (such as repartir - to distribute) but the specific form is confusing.  I'm hopeful that someone can, first, help me understand this specific instance and, second, recommend a way to understand what all of this means.  Simply looking at verb conjugation charts does not help.  Most sites on the 'net seem to only provide this.  Do I have to go back to school to understand this?  I did well in English but these forms are lost in the cobwebs.  How did you overcome this issue and effectively study this?
Thanks!

Comment: In order to provide an explanation for this specific instance, it would be helpful with context for this specific instance.

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me but a representative sentence would be, "Sería mejor que repartiera periódicos en vez de buscarte trabajo."

Comment: @McArthey What would you like to know exactly? I think you should remove all that frustration from your question, as it is quite irrelevant for the spirit of Spanish.SE ;)

Comment: +1 for the laugh.  I will edit in an attempt to clarify after I have another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is over one month old, but let me enter the conversation, as I do not fully agree with any of the previous answers.

The original sentence seemed to be

> Sería mejor que (yo) repartiera periódicos en vez de buscarte trabajo

which might be translated as

> It would be better (for me) to distribute newspapers instead of looking for a job for you

So let's go for it...

- "Repartiera" is not conditional, but subjunctive (distributed)
- "Sería" is conditional (would be)
- "Repartiera" is not present tense, but past tense (present would be "reparta").
- Why "repartiera" (subjunctive?) and not "repartia" (indicative past)? We use subjunctive when something is a wish or depends on a condition, and indicative to express facts. Let me include a few examples:

> I distributed newspapers when I lived in XXX = Yo repartía periodicos cuando vivía en XXX (a fact: indicative)
>
> I wish I distributed newspapers, as I would have more spare time = Ójala repartiera periódicos, porque tendría más tiempo libre (a wish: subjunctive)
>
> If I distributed newspapers, I would have more spare time = Si repartiera periódicos,  tendría más tiempo libre (the beginning of a conditional sentence)

Comment: Note that you can also say *yo repartía* as *I would distribute*, seen as a repeated action in the past.

Comment: Clarification: Subjunctive comes from subjunction, which means that a sentence is *included* or *subordinated* in another sentence. We use specific tenses for subjunctions, like this case. There's no direct equivalence in english.

Comment: Anyway, saying "Seria mejor que yo repartiera" is not to well-constructed in spanish. By the context, which is well-translated into english, the spanish sentence should be "Seria mejor que yo reparta" since it is a potential situation to occur (in quichua is easier to explain), and not regarding a frequent action done in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing @McArthey's sentence, I agree with the sample sentence. Repartiera is more like "To Distribute" or "To Hand Out" in a preterit or past representation of a verb.

So translating his sample sentence is like "It would be better to [pass out | hand out | distrubute] newspaper instead of looking for a job."

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Consulta nuestro [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq) para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Animamos a los usuarios a que las respuestas sean elaboradas y con referencias que las soporten, obviando las opiniones personales. Puedes editar tu respuesta para reflejar esto. ¡Esperamos que contribuyas a menudo al sitio!

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence "Sería mejor que repartiera periódicos..." the word "repartiera" is in conditional form, indicating that it's an improbable thing to happen...

The sentenced is a transformation of this one: "Si yo repartiera periódicos sería mejor que buscarte trabajo".

Sorry for my english ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment "Sería mejor que (yo) repartiera periódicos en vez de buscarte trabajo."

'Repartiera' corresponds to the 1st person subjunctive present.

Comment: Agreed.  It's also worth mentioning that "sería" is a conditional.

Comment: "Sería mejor que (él) repartiera periódicos en vez de buscarte trabajo."